# How to store references of integer array in array

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to store

```
int[] a=new int[10];
int[] b=new int[20];
int[] c=new int[30];
int[] d=new int[40];
```

variables a,b,c,d in an array. I don't know how to do it. For user defined type such as objects of `myclass` I can create an array of type `myclass` such as

```
myclass[] m=new myclass[2];
```

and store references in this array. I don't know how to do this for primitive data types such as int, char etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for array of array

```
int [][] arrayOfArray = { intarray1, intarray2, ..};
```

So

```
int [][] arrayOfArray = { a, b, ..};
```

**Update:**

```
int store[][]=new int[4][];
        store[0] = a; 
        store[1] = b; 
        store[2] = c;
        store[3] = d;
```

Comment: is'nt the question about array of references to arrays of ints? or am i confused?

Comment: `I am trying to store [...] reference of a,b,c,d in an array` is what confused me :-)

Comment: @Koushik  That is fine. OP asked both the questions , If I'm not confused :)

Comment: @Koushik lets just say that I have four integer array a,b,c,d as defined above now I want to store a,b,c,d in an array so I can get them via index and use them.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I am doing this 
`int[] a=new int[10]; int[] b=new int[20]; int[] c=new int[30]; int[] d=new int[40]; Integer store[]=new Integer[4]; store[0]=a;`
It is showing error

Comment: @RiteshSangwan You are doing wrong. You need a 2d array not the single array. See the second half of my post.

Answer (score 3):

> I am trying to store variables a,b,c,d in an array.

You want a *two-dimensional* array, which is actually an array of arrays:

```
int[][] arys = new int[4][];
arys[0] = a; 
arys[1] = b; 
arys[2] = c;
arys[3] = d;
```

Comment: there is a typo, it should be `new int[4][];`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Integer` or `Character` or `Boolean` e.g.:

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[10];
```